# Disable controls too slow

Tags: c#, winforms

Using this method:

```
    private void disableControls()
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            c.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

On a form which has only 5 controls, why is it so slow?

You can clearly see each control being disabled.

Edit:

Here are some more details:

The only event handler I have in the form is bound to the IndexChanged of a comboBox.

The form where I am running this method is a fresh form called from a parent form using showDialog.

In fact, the disable controls method is the first thing that is called when you click the button.

I really don't know why it's doing that, I will try to reboot and see if it gets better.

Comment: It shouldn't be that slow. You obviously have something going on elsewhere in your code, or on your computer. More details are necessary.

Comment: I haven't written an interesting winforms app in years, so I don't know the answer, but I'm curious whether you have a lot of stuff going on in the background while you're running this.

Comment: Why not just call `this.Enabled = false`?

Comment: Do you have events wired to the `Enabled` property value changing?

Comment: I recently used this on a half dozen controls, while running a reasonably processor-intensive background task, and had no problem at all. What type of controls are these, are they bound to anything else, are event handlers being invoked, what other circumstances may be causing the problem?

Comment: It depends on what are you doing, maybe in your code, there is something work on controls or something in background and this make your form slow when you try to disable controls.

Comment: Run your program in a profiler to see where it's spending so much of its time.  This could help you find any events being triggered from your code that you didn't think would be triggered.

Comment: I recently suffered from this problem too. I changed to WPF instead. The reason I think is toggle Enabled causes immediate control repaint, which is slow, and I don't know how to change this kind of repaint feature.

Answer (score 1):

Unable to reproduce. Here's a short but complete program which disables the controls pretty quickly. If you can come up with a similar one which is slow, we can work out *why* it's slow.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Form form = new Form();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button
            {
                Text = "Dummy",
                Location = new Point(10, i * 25)
            };
            form.Controls.Add(button);
        }
        Button disabler = new Button
        {
            Text = "Disable",
            Location = new Point(10, 100)
        };
        disabler.Click += delegate
        {
            foreach (Control c in form.Controls)
            {
                c.Enabled = false;
            }
        };
        form.Controls.Add(disabler);
        Application.Run(form);
    }                   
}
```